# Linkify without showing the full url

Tags: android, linkify

I have used

```
Linkify.addLinks(textview, Linkify.ALL);
```

To make a TextView clickable, and to act like, well, a link. The problem is, if the link is too large, it looks very ugly. Is there any way to make it shorter, or substitute the url for a text? Anybody knows of a library that can suit me?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use `urlshortner` google api to short url.

Comment: or you can ellipsis at the end. or make it scrollable or marqee

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following in the `textView.setText()` method:

```
Html.fromHtml("A text with a <a href=\"http://somelonglink\">link</a>")
```

Comment: Getting out of job right now...will try it tomorrow, and will upvote if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. The word link looks like a link, but does not answer to clicking. I tried to Linkify the textView, but didn't work. We have changed the layout, so now instead of textviews are buttons, so I don't need a way to shorten the url now. Thanks for trying, anyway.

Comment: Okay. BTW it should solve the problem if you call `textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` on your textView.